# Mysql privileges lost automatically

Tags: mysql, remote-access, privileges, remote-server, mysql-5.1

I'm using Mysql 5.1. I give all privileges to mysql user for remote access. But sometimes privileges automatically lost. I give all privileges again, it works. What can be the reason?

Comment: in what scenarios the privileges are lost?

Comment: I didn't check it. But remote access becomes impossible. After giving all privileges again, works normally.

Comment: you need to figure out in what cases this happens... maybe you have a cron that resets the privileges ... Try also to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after you grant them and see if this happens again